# Static int list index not working properly

Tags: c#

I have a list of ints I'll use later:

```
public class Strms
{
    public static List<int> _AList;

    static Strms()
    {
        _AList = new List<int>();
    }

    public Strms()
    {
        _AList.Add(265);
        _AList.Add(694);
        _AList.Add(678);
        _AList.Add(364);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use an index of the list I just created, here:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        var keys = new List<string>();
        keys.Add("item1");
        keys.Add("item2");
        keys.Add("item3");
        keys.Add("item4");

        foreach (var item in keys.OfType<string>().Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
        {
                int ItemNumber = item.i;
                int stream = Strms._AList[ItemNumber];
                Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream, true);
                MessageBox.Show(item.x);
        }

    }
```

I recieve "Index was out of range" error.

What Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you "need" to keep this design(adding items to the list only when strms is instantiated) then you could do this - int stream = Strms._AList.ElementAtOrDefault(ItemNumber); which if no element is present stream will recieve 0 because its the default of int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**
   Your list is not populated, as you are populating it in the public constructor, which will only be called when you create an instance of it.

Solution:

You have 3 solutions here

Either change the static constructor like this

```
static Strms()
        {
            _AList = new List<int>();
            _AList.Add(0);
            _AList.Add(1);
            _AList.Add(1);
            _AList.Add(1);
        }
```

or create an instance of your class strms to call the public constructor. Like

```
Strms s = new Strms();
```

or a public static method to fill the list, before your foreach loop. Like

```
public static void InitializeList()    
{
     _AList.Add(0);
     _AList.Add(1);
     _AList.Add(1);
     _AList.Add(1);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only adding items to the static list when you create an instance of the `Strms` class. So the list is naturally empty until you create an instance.

Comment: " So the list is naturally empty until you create an instance",you mean until you add items?(the list is instantiated by the static ctor) :)

Comment: @terrybozzio - The list is instantiated by the static constructor, but items are only added to the list when a class instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 constructors, only the non-static one is inserting items into the list and doesn't get called unless you create an instance of it. Either create an instance or move that code into the static constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list in its definition, rather than in the constructor for the class, since it's static. Try using this definition instead:

```
public static List<int> _AList = new List<int>{0,1,1,1};
```

and removing the code from the other 2 methods.